# how to print a pdf file without using adobe reader in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I have a pdf in ticket format of an 80mm invoice. How can I print without using adobe reader.
Is there a library that can help me work?

I tried various tools but none gave me a solution, even using adobe reader there are times when it does not send to print and it is uncomfortable for the client.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Spire.PDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/) nuget package which supports multiple printing scenarios.
The following code shows how to print a PDF using the default printer:

```
using Spire.Pdf;

namespace PrintWithDefaultPrinter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create PdfDocument object
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

            //Load a PDF file
            doc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.pdf");

            //Print with default printer 
            doc.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

More printing options can be found in this documentation: [C#/VB.NET: Print PDF Documents](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Print/How-to-print-PDF-document-in-C.html).

Comment: Do you know any other bookstore that is free?

Answer (score 0):

You can silent print any PDF file by using the free library PDFium, any other not free library is pure scam. Just add the PDFium free library to your project by using NuGET and here is the code you need in a single static method:

```
public static void PrintFileWithPDFium(string file, string printer_name, short copy_number = 1)
{
    // Create the printer settings for our printer
    PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
    {
        PrinterName = printer_name,
        Copies = copy_number,
    };
    // Now print the PDF document
    using (PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(file))
    {
        using (PrintDocument printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
        {
            printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
            //printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
            printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            printDocument.OriginAtMargins = false;
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Any issues just comment this post, I'm glad to help you with this